# Compare MySql Tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables with numbers in each:

For expamle ->

Table 1:
1
2
3
4
5

Table 2: 
5
3
1

I'm trying to write a query that displays any values that are in table 1 but aren't in table 2 (and the other way round). The numbers could be in any order and are both primary keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make two separate queries using [`WHERE NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), then combine their output with [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html).

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

if you edit your question and give your table schema I could give more clear answer.
Now I am just assuming.

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id
where t2.id is null
```

**alternative:**

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
where t1.id not in (select id from table2)
```

Comment: *"(and the other way round)"*